# Dictionary values change when filling with a list when this list is being iterated over a loop

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key, key-value

I am trying to fill a dictionary where the keys are integers and the values are lists. The lists are simply a list of integers that gets longer with each position in the dictionary, so I am looking for a result such as:

```
{0:[0], 1:[0,1], 2:[0,1,2], 3:[0,1,2,3] ...
```

I have tried with this code

```
dictfinal = {}
List = []
for i in range(0,3):
```

But the result I get is:

```
[0]
{0: [0]}
[0, 1]
{0: [0, 1], 1: [0, 1]}
[0, 1, 2]
{0: [0, 1, 2], 1: [0, 1, 2], 2: [0, 1, 2]}
```

As you can see, with each iteration it seems that the values of the previous keys already defined seem to be changing!

When writing the same code, but filling the values with integers instead of lists this problem does not appear...

```
dictfinal = {}
List = []
for i in range(0,3):
      List.append(i)
      dictfinal.update({i:i})
      print(List)
      print(dictfinal)
```

Gives:

```
[0]
{0: 0}
[0, 1]
{0: 0, 1: 1}
[0, 1, 2]
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2}
```

Which is exactly what I expect... So why doesn't it work for the case when working with a list?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I clone a list so that it doesn't change unexpectedly after assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-do-i-clone-a-list-so-that-it-doesnt-change-unexpectedly-after-assignment)

Comment: when you assign list to variable then it doesn't duplicate it but it use only reference - so later you use the same list in all places. You may need to use `your_list.copy()` or `copy.deepcopy(your_list)` if you have more complex objects in list. If you run code on [PythonTutor](https://pythontutor.com/) then you should see visualization which shows arrows to the same list in memory

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you're using the same list as a value for each key of the final dictionary.

Instead, for each key create a new list that is independent of other lists:

```py
dictfinal = {}
for i in range(3):
    dictfinal[i] = list(range(i + 1))

print(dictfinal)
```

Prints:

```
{0: [0], 1: [0, 1], 2: [0, 1, 2]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use a comprehension:

```
my_dict = {i : list(range(i+1)) for i in range (5)}
```

gives:

{0: [0], 1: [0, 1], 2: [0, 1, 2], 3: [0, 1, 2, 3], 4: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]}

Answer (score 0):

To populate your dictionary in your (incomplete) first code, you probably do:
`dictfinal.update({i:List})`

You need to replace `List` there with a **copy**, which can be done in many ways. For example:

```
List.copy()
list(List)
[*List]
...
```